# Progress bar with ngRoute in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngroute

Hi currently i am using ngRoute to fetch template from backend. but because of the size of template, it freezes till the template is loaded. What i want is a progress bar that shows the status of template as it is *downloading* .

I have found that ngProgress might be something that i want but i have not been able to integrate the same. Here is a small snippet for the ngRoute

```
App.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
                templateUrl : '/templates/home.html',
                controller  : 'landing'
            })
        .when('/login', {
                templateUrl : '/templates/login.html',
                controller  : 'authCtl'
            })
        .when('/signup', {
                templateUrl : '/templates/signup.html',
                controller  : 'authCtl'
            })
        .otherwise({
                templateUrl : '/templates/404.html',
                controller  : 'mainController'
        });
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

Comment: https://www.phase2technology.com/blog/angularjs-two-ways-loading-animations/

Comment: https://github.com/chieffancypants/angular-loading-bar try this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried angular-loading-bar?
https://chieffancypants.github.io/angular-loading-bar/